# key definition for 'fetch.message.max.bytes' in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am not sure how to define the key for the message size of my `KafkaSpouts`.
My example:

```
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put("fetch.message.max.bytes", "2097152"); // 2MB
props.put(KafkaSpoutConfig.Consumer.GROUP_ID, group);
```

I searched for the constant key definition of `"fetch.message.max.bytes"` without succeed. 
I expect this key in `KafkaSpoutConfig.Consumer` or at least `KafkaSpoutConfig`.

Anyone know the correct location?

Answer (score 0):

Storm's `KafkaSpout` does not offer all available keys as perdefined members. However, if you know the name of the key, you can safely use a String (as shown in your example) of use a Kafka class that defines the key.